# Paper Explanation Part

Tags: feature-request, suggestion

I have a suggestion. Data Science consists of so many different fields which are updated ever day. I know `StackOverflow` has cancelled it but once it had a possibility for its folks to put documentation of different programming languages. In our field there are so many pioneer papers that are a bit hard to interpret. I recommend putting a part in the website that people put documentation about different papers.

Comment: It is a great idea. But, I guess it is not a SO-style model. The papers coming out, are just too many for documenting :)

Comment: @Dawny33 that's true but I guess there are always papers that make a new path. Those can be discussed :)

Comment: "putting a part in the website that people put documentation about different papers." -> could you please expand on that?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Do you remember the documentation part in Stackoverflow? something like that.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt e.x. YOLO paper or the first LSTM paper in 90s, I guess these are papaer which are really important and are hard to interpret. It will be really good if people share their opinion about those. Or maybe interpreting different formulas in papers that usually do not have detailed explanations.

Comment: @Media Thanks, I see. I agree it'd be nice to have in some form. There could be some general opinion section, then some more specific QAs about the paper. (FYI: [Why doesn't arXiv have a comment section?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/32367/452))

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt thanks, yes I guess it will be very nice :)